# Doubts in Volume, Hypervolume in $R^4$

Tags: integration, volume, dimension-theory-analysis

Recently I was reading about triple integrals and I came across the statement -

> "We saw that a double integral could be thought of as the volume under
>   a two-dimensional surface. It turns out that the triple integral
>   simply generalizes this idea: it can be thought of as representing the
>   hypervolume under a three-dimensional hypersurface w=f(x,y,z) whose
>   graph lies in $R^4$"

My doubts are:

1. We imagine or assume Volume in $R^3$ as space enclosed by a curve. But what can be imagined for a hypervolume.
2. We can calculate Area in $R^2$ as well as $R^3$. So in $R^4$, using same analogy can we calculate Volume of curves in $R^4$.
3. Are volume and hypervolume different quantities in $R^4$?

I'm in a confused state with all these questions. Pl. Help me.

Thanks for everyone in advance

Answer (score 1):

A square has 1-dimensional edges, which have lengths.

A cube has 1d edges (which have lengths) and 2d faces (which have area).

A hypercube is a 4 dimensional object.  It is bounded by several cubes (similar to how a cube is bounded by many faces).  These bounding cubes have volume.  The hypercube has a hypervolume of 1*1*1*1 (it is 1 unit long in each of the 4 directions).

This corresponds to the case of integrating w=f(x,y,z)=1 over $0\leq x,y,z\leq1$.

Comment: A unit square has a perimeter 4. An unit cube has a surface area 6. Similarly What is the surface volume of a hypercube? (Sorry if i misused the term surface volume, my intention of using it was analogy)

Comment: @Prasanna : following your square's perimeter of 4 [linear units] and cube's area of 6 [square units], the tesseract's surface volume would be 8 [cubic units]. Preceding these with a line segment's boundary of 2 [DIM 0 units], the sequence [for n-dimensional cubes] builds itself as DIM n surface = 2^n [in units of n-1].